# SQL Statement with parameter passing executes in TOAD editor but gives error at controller side

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, oracle

I am trying to execute a sql statement with parameter passing which runs in toad editor but gives error at the controller side. here is code

```
string query ="Select 
                 LOC_SYS_ID,
                 LOC_CODE,
                 LOC_NAME 
             FROM F_LOCATION 
             WHERE (LOC_SYS_ID like :P1 
                    or LOC_CODE like :P1 
                    or LOC_NAME like :P1) 
                 and ROWNUM <= 50 
                 and LOC_EM_SYS_ID = :P2";

IEnumerable queryResult = dbm.Database
                             .SqlQuery(resultType, 
                                       query , 
                                       new object[] {"Q%",3 });
```

At the controller side it throws the exception as

> ORA-01008: not all variables bound

However in TOAD editor its executing without any exception.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you passing 4 values to the query? It doesn't matter if the names of first three bind variables are same, but if the query is used dynamically or for some third party programming language, you have to pass as many values as the number of bind variables, in your case it is 4.

In toad its working because you are running this query as simple SQL query, not as a dynamic statement, as such p1 is valid for every where it is used in the query.

Comment: Yes it worked, but when the query was Select LOC_SYS_ID,LOC_CODE,LOC_NAME FROM F_EMIRATES_LOCATION WHERE (LOC_SYS_ID like :P0 or LOC_CODE like :P0 or LOC_NAME like :P0) and ROWNUM <= 50 then i was passing only 1 argument and it was executing without any exception

Comment: Agree, but you did it in Toad(I guess) as a SQL statement, The bind variable P0 and its value is valid for that session throughout. But when you are using this SQL statement from some other programming environment, you have to pass the values since the variable name P0 is not known to Oracle, it understands number of bind variables (not by name p0 or p1) and its value. Hope it answers your question.